# How do I use the existing tables in Postgres DB and use them in Django

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I'm new to Django and i'm trying to build a web console for the users who can view, insert/update/delete data to PostgreSQL DB.

I have couple of tables already created which i want to use. I have used below command to inspect the tables and use them in Django models

$ python manage.py inspectdb bkp_fulfilment_product_provider > models.py

When I run the above command I get a error as below:
**Version**:

PostgresSql Version 9.2.18 and Django version 3.1
**Error:**

```
# This is an auto-generated Django model module.
# You'll have to do the following manually to clean this up:
#   * Rearrange models' order
#   * Make sure each model has one field with primary_key=True
#   * Make sure each `ForeignKey` and `OneToOneField` has `on_delete` set to the desired behaviour
#   * Remove `managed = False` lines if you wish to allow Django to create, modify, and delete the table
# Feel free to rename the models, but don't rename db_table values or field names.
    from `django.db` import models
# Unable to inspect table bkp_fulfilment_product_provider
# The error was: syntax error at or near `WITH ORDINALITY`
LINE 6:                        FROM `unnest(c.conkey)` WITH ORDINALITY co...
```

Comment: what is the postgres and django version you are using, also sql to create  that particular table

Comment: PostgresSql Version 9.2.18 and Django version 3.1. Table already exist in the DB, CREATE TABLE bkp_fulfilment_product_provider (
 product_code varchar(100) NULL,
 fulfilment_provider_code varchar(100) NULL,
 is_primary bool NULL,
 on_hand_stock int4 NULL,
 on_order_stock int4 NULL
);

Comment: Your PostgreSQL version is not supported with Django version you are trying to use
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/databases/#postgresql-notes
You should update PostgreSQL

Comment: Thanks iklinac, I don't think we will be able to upgrade DataBase. You have anyother suggestion. My intention here is to get my hands dirty with python and build a web interface for users

Comment: As I already said you can use older version but both postgre and django versions are considered old and would still advise database update

Comment: Postgres 9.2 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Your PostgreSQL minor version is 4 years old and already not [fix supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/) for 3 years by PostgreSQL

Last version of Django that support this database version is [1.10](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/databases/#postgresql-notes) and it is considered insecure

You should update your PostgreSQL to new version